# PHP - How to iterate through every element in an array with an unknown number of dimensions

Tags: php, arrays

So I'm trying to iterate through an array that looks like the following.  However, I'm deriving this array from files on the filesystem, so the more directories that are created the more dimensions this array will have.

I have tried several different things using foreach but I can't seem to get something working dynamically.  I also had some success with PHP 5.5's list function, but that only got me so far in the array structure before it stopped helping.

Any ideas?

```
Array
(
    [First Response Manual] => Array
        (
            [0] => Facilities Maintenance-Locksmith Standby Schedule.pdf
            [1] => First Response Manual 2011.pdf
            [2] => First Response Manual Fall 2010.pdf
            [3] => ORL_Facilities_Maint_and_ Lock_schedule_12 22 2011---03 15 12.pdf
        )

    [Phone Guides] => Array
        (
            [0] => ORL_Facilities_Maint_and_ Lock_schedule_01 21 2011---04 14 11.pdf
            [1] => ORL_Facilities_Maint_and_ Lock_schedule_08 06 2010---10 28 10.pdf
            [2] => Phone Guide.pdf
        )

    [0] => RA Job Manual.pdf
    [RA Manual] => Array
        (
            [0] => Foreword.doc
            [1] => RA Job Manual - Updated August 2012.pdf
            [2] => RA Job Manual - Updated June 2011.doc
        )

    [Section 1 - Resources] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12 - Very Important Phone Numbers.doc
            [1] => AA List- 2009.doc
            [2] => Library Handout.pdf
            [3] => Mental Health Resources.docx
            [4] => ORL Resource Library.xls
            [5] => RA Parent Tips.docx
            [6] => event calendar brochure- LIT.docx
            [7] => iServiceDesk Procedures.doc
        )

    [Section 2 - Emergency Procedures] => Array
        (
            [0] => Emergency Situations.doc
            [1] => Thumbs.db
            [2] => bomb threat check list.jpg
            [3] => emergency quick ref sheet.pub
            [4] => map to Fort Hospital.jpg
            [5] => map to Fort Hospital.pdf
        )

    [Section 3 - Helping Skills] => Array
        (
            [Academics] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Academic Advising Primer for RA Staff.docx
                    [1] => Academic Survival Skills.doc
                    [2] => Academics.doc
                    [3] => Developmental Issues.doc
                )

            [Communication] => Array
                (
                    [0] => American Idioms.doc
                    [1] => Aspergers 101.ppsx
                    [2] => Conflict Mediation.doc
                    [3] => First Year Students.doc
                    [4] => Helping Skills.doc
                    [5] => International Students.doc
                    [6] => LGBT Ally.doc
                    [7] => LGBT Students.doc
                    [8] => Peer Counseling.doc
                    [9] => Referrals.doc
                    [10] => Resolving Roommate Conflicts.doc
                )

            [Health and Safety] => Array
                (
                    [0] => AIDS and HIV.doc
                    [1] => Alcohol 2.doc
                    [2] => Alcohol.doc
                    [3] => Dating Violence.doc
                    [4] => Depression.doc
                    [5] => Drug Abuse.doc
                    [6] => Eating Disorders.doc
                    [7] => Evaluating Eating and Exercise Habits.pdf
                    [8] => Grief.doc
                    [9] => Males With Eating Disorders.doc
                    [10] => Meningitis.doc
                    [11] => National Eating Disorder Organizations.doc
                    [12] => STDs (2).doc
                    [13] => STDs.doc
                    [14] => Sexual Assault Acquaintance.doc
                    [15] => Sexual Assault.doc
                    [16] => Sexual Harassment.doc
                    [17] => Stress.doc
                    [18] => Substance Abuse Dependence.doc
                    [19] => Suicide.doc
                    [20] => stalking brochure.pdf
                )

        )
)
```

Comment: I would try the [is_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php) function and if so, run recursively into that.

Comment: a search for "foreach loop recrsive" re turns a large number of hits, it depends on your exact requirements

Comment: If this is for the filesystem what dont you just use `RecursiveDirectoryIterator`... Along those same lines there is also `RecursiveArrayIterator`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have PHP 5.5, you could do it with generators:

```
function recursiveIterate($a)
{
    if (is_array($a) || $a instanceof \Traversable) {
        foreach ($a as $entry) {
            foreach (recursiveIterate($entry) as $value) yield $value;
        }
    } else yield $a;
}

$myBigArray = array(/* stuff */);
foreach (recursiveIterate($myBigArray) as $value) {
    //do something with $value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SPL contains iterators for a variety of things. For example here you could use the `RecursiveArrayIterator`:

```
$iter = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($arr), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
foreach ($iter as $k => $v
    if (is_array($v)) {
        print "$k\n";
    } else {
        print "$v\n";
    }
}
```

But you mention this is coming from the filesystem so why not just use `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` to being with:

```
$dirIter = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('/path/to/dir', FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS|FilesystemIterator::CURRENT_AS_FILEINFO|FilesystemIterator::KEY_AS_PATHNAME);
$iter = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dirIter, RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

foreach ($iter as $k => $v) {
    $line = "%s: %s\n";
    printf($line, 'pathname', $v->getPathname());
    printf($line, 'filename', $v->getFilename());
    printf($line, 'path', $v->getPath());
}
```